# How to redirect without GET parameters using the routing?

Tags: php, redirect, symfony, routes, symfony-2.2

My routing is defined like this :

```
# New URLs
article_show:
    pattern:  /article/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Article:show }

# Old URLs
article_show_legacy:
    path:            /article-{id}-{param}.html
    requirements:
        param: foo|bar
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route:       article_show
        permanent:   true
```

I'd like to know how I can redirect `article_show_legacy` to `article_show` without `param` parameter. At the moment whenever I access `/article-1-foo.html` (for example), I'm redirected to `/article/1?param=foo`. I would like to discard `?param=foo` so I'm redirected to `/article/1`.

I know I can create one route for `foo` and one route for `bar` but in my case there's more cases.

Do I have to write my own redirect controller ?

Comment: I normally handle this s business logic in my controllers or twigs,  Are you wanting a config-only type solution or should I post that type of response?

Comment: I know I can handle that in a controller, but I wondered if the routing component provided something to handle this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your own redirect controller or just create redirect method in any existing controller.

Check `redirect` action of the `RedirectController` in `../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/RedirectController.php` for mor details.

Some example (I added third option `stripAttributes`):

```
public function redirectAction($route, $permanent = false, $stripAttributes = false)
{
    if ('' == $route) {
        return new Response(null, $permanent ? 410 : 404);
    }

    $attributes = array();
    if (!$stripAttributes) {
        $attributes = $this->container->get('request')->attributes->get('_route_params');
        unset($attributes['route'], 
              $attributes['permanent'], 
              $attributes['stripAttributes']);
    }

    return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate($route, $attributes, UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL), $permanent ? 301 : 302);
}
```

Comment: Great ! I just did something similar and used an `array` as the third parameter.